# Using UIWebView to load web images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is is possible to download images inside the UIWebView and load it into a UIImage? I would like to allow the user to grab an email from a web site and load it into my app. I guess the manual way right now would to let the user download the image to their photo album and then I can allow the person to load it up by accessing the photo album.  I'm trying to make it a bit more smooth so if anyone can shed any light on this that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save images downloaded in your UIWebView unless they are in base64 format.

Actually the only thing you can do is catching the source code of the page using javascript and then save it as a string. (that's why images should be in base64 format).

Comment: So if a user decides to save a image from a random website there's no way to catch that image?  I guess there's no way of enforcing the base64 format in the wild web anyway. Regarding your second option, how do you go about doing something like that? If you can get the page, then you would try to parse out all images links?

Comment: exactly. to get the html source code, you have to implement the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method : 
NSString *html = [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest)? If you intercepted page loading requests, ran them through that system, then loaded the results into your UIWebView you could intercept the images along the way.